# Fullcalendar & Bootstrap: Callbacks work for .modal() but not .dropdown('toggle')

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

I am building a calendar application and would like a context menu to be triggered when a user drags a selection of time or clicks on a time of day. (Using Bootstrap's `.dropdown()` on an element positioned absolutely at `jsEvent.pageX,jsEvent.pageY`).

Unfortunately there's a problem - The dropdown menu does not appear to be triggered correctly. What is strange is that `.modal()` triggers just perfectly.

My assumption is that the code Fullcalendar uses to listen to and capture the events in order to acknowledge/render user selection is preventing Bootstrap from triggering correctly, but why not fail for `.modal()` as well?

Any help is much appreciated.

**jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sqjz558x/**

```
function eventCreate(start, end, jsEvent, view) {
  // Works 
  //$('.modal-new-event').modal(); 

  // Doesn't work, notice highlighting of button during drag
  $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown('toggle'); 

  // Works but is unreliable (using unselect handler)
  //$('.dropdown-menu').toggle(); 
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        selectable: true,
        select: function (start, end, jsEvent, view) {
          return eventCreate(start, end, jsEvent, view); 
        },      
        dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) { 
          return eventCreate(date, null, jsEvent, view); 
        },
        unselect: function (view, jsEvent) { 
         // $('.dropdown-menu').toggle();
        }       
    })
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just stop the event propagation in the calendar:

```
document.getElementById("calendar").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

See working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2yofpfgj/3/)

The `dropdown` is being opened by the original click event. Then the event propagates, triggered again and closes the `dropdown`. `e.stopPropagation();` will prevent this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

The problem that you have is that fullcalendar triggers a `click` event for the `document` after the selection (or any click inside your calendar) is made, and this is a problem because the bootstrap's dropdown's `hide` function is bind to `$(document).click()`.

What actually happen here is that your dropdown menu is shown, but immediately after that it gets hidden due to the trigger of the click on `document`

> Not a good solution (but it works) - you can unbind the click on the document:
>
> ```
> $(document).unbind('click');
> ```
>
> Really not recommended because you don't really know what you are going to mess, [but it works](https://jsfiddle.net/aa843pzr/) (really, check it! )

You can see there that I also made sure to toggle the drop-down on `unselect`.

---

A much better solution is to check when do we really need to close the dropdown, and it the dropdown is about to get hide, but shouldn't - stop it from being hidden. In order to do that we needed a new variable to tell us whether we need to keep the dropdown open or not:

- when selection is done - we need to keep it open
- when unselect - it's ok to close it

This way - even if the calendar is triggering the `$(document).click()` event - since we know that we are in a `select` state - we shouldn't hide the menu:

```
var keepDropdownOpen = false;

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    selectable: true,
    select: function (start, end, jsEvent, view) {
        // On select - keep the dropdown open
        keepDropdownOpen = true;
        return eventCreate(start, end, jsEvent, view); 
    },      
    dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) { 
        //return eventCreate(date, null, jsEvent, view); 
    },
    unselect: function (view, jsEvent) { 
        // On unselect - no need to keep the dropdown open
        keepDropdownOpen = false;
        $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown('toggle');
    }
});
$('.dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function (e) {
    // If we should keep the dropdown open - just return false
    if (keepDropdownOpen) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
})
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/5yx4z534/

Answer (score 0):

In fact it is triggered twice: Selection also generates click event, so eventCreate() is called twice and, hence, dropdown is toggled twice returning to its original state.

If you comment out eventCreate() call in click event then both click and selection works as (I think) you expect because when you click single cell you are actually performing a selection of single cell length. See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sqjz558x/1/):

```
dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) { 
    ////return eventCreate(date, null, jsEvent, view); 
},
```

...What I observe is that a second click triggers again the same events (which it seems right to me) but third not. But I think this is regarding to *fullCalendar* plugin internals...

Also, note that clicking to distinct cell while dropdown is opened toggles it again causing it to be closed instead of opened. So probably you should better use some ("open") function (if exists, I did'nt dive into) or check its status before toggling it again.